# Firebase function test initialisation fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

Trying to test my Firebase cloud functions. I have followed the documentation and I get the following error when running the tests. I have tried generating different keys, I get to the service key window through Firebase so it is the correct project. The error occurs when I run the tests: `npm test`

```
Error: Options object {"_fieldsProto":{"foo":{"stringValue":"bar"}},"_ref":{"_firestore":{"_settings":{"credentials":{"private_key":"KEY","client_email":"project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"},"projectId":"project","firebaseVersion":"8.13.0","libName":"gccl","libVersion":"3.8.6 fire/8.13.0"},"_settingsFrozen":false,"_serializer":{"allowUndefined":false},"_projectId":"project","registeredListenersCount":0,"_lastSuccessfulRequest":0,"_backoffSettings":{"initialDelayMs":100,"maxDelayMs":60000,"backoffFactor":1.3},"_preferTransactions":false,"_clientPool":{"concurrentOperationLimit":100,"maxIdleClients":1,"activeClients":{},"terminated":false,"terminateDeferred":{"promise":{}}}},"_path":{"segments":["document","path"],"projectId":"project","databaseId":"(default)"},"_converter":{}},"_serializer":{"allowUndefined":false},"_readTime":{"_seconds":1602169684,"_nanoseconds":285000000},"_createTime":{"_seconds":1602169684,"_nanoseconds":285000000},"_updateTime":{"_seconds":1602169684,"_nanoseconds":285000000}} has invalid key "_fieldsProto"
    at /home//Desktop/Work/test-app/app/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/main.js:99:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at _checkOptionValidity (/home//Desktop/Work/test-app/app/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/main.js:97:26)
    at scheduledWrapped (/home//Desktop/Work/test-app/app/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/main.js:36:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home//Desktop/Work/test-app/app/functions/index.test.js:98:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:791:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.exports.requireOrImport (/home//Desktop/Work/test-app/app/functions/node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js:20:12)
    at Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (/home//Desktop/Work/test-app/app/functions/node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js:33:34)
    at Mocha.loadFilesAsync (/home//Desktop/Work/test-app/app/functions/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:427:19)
    at singleRun (/home//Desktop/Work/test-app/app/functions/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:156:15)
    at exports.runMocha (/home//Desktop/Work/test-app/app/functions/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:225:10)
    at Object.exports.handler (/home//Desktop/Work/test-app/app/functions/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:366:11)
    at /home//Desktop/Work/test-app/app/functions/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:241:49


const test = require('firebase-functions-test')({
     databaseURL: "####",
     storageBucket: "####",
     projectId: "#####",   }, './key.json');
 
 
const myFunctions = require('./index.js');
 
const wrapped = test.wrap(myFunctions.testFunction);
const snap = test.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot({foo: 'bar'}, 'document/path'); 
wrapped(snap); 
test.cleanup();
```

Followed this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec index.test.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "reportdatasummary": "file:reportdatasummary"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "mocha": "^8.1.3",
    "reportdatasummary": "file:reportdatasummary"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Hi @AlexTaylor could you please add more details to your case? If you could provide the documentation and exact step you started facing the error, more information about your Firestore database, etc., will help the Community to have a better understanding of your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says invalid key "_fieldProto", and if you look at what that dict actually holds:

```
"fieldsProto":{"foo":{"stringValue":"bar"}}
```

I think that you just have to remove the param that you are passing into your wrapped function.

```
const wrapped = test.wrap(myFunctions.testFunction);
wrapped(); 
test.cleanup();
```